# once, twice, thrice... was there more?

Tags: adverbs, history, archaicisms

I realize everyone uses 'four times', 'five times'... in case of denoting something repeating more than three times. Even 'thrice' is currently gradually going extinct.

But did English ever possess single-word expression that denoted 'four times', or any for higher number, or was 'thrice' always the highest single-word adverb to denote a number of times something repeats?

Comment: @Josh61: Since you have the rep to closevote as a duplicate, I don't understand why you didn't do this, having gone to the trouble of actually *finding* the original.

Comment: The suffix is _-fold_: _three-fold, eighteen-fold, manifold_. In German it's _-fach_: _einfach, dreifach_.